# join two tables and show records only having specific conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, `quotation` and `comparitive`.

Table `quotation` has fields: `tender_id, supplier_name`

Table `comparitive` has fields: `tender_id, sup_name,make,shelf_life,datasheet,coc`

Now what I want is I need a query which joins these two tables and show records where `quotation.tender_id=comparitive.tender_id and comparitive.tender_id=$tender_id and comparitive.sup_name IN quotation.supplier_name`.

How can I achieve that? I have tried different ways but desired output is not coming.

This is what I have tried.

```
 SELECT comparitive_statement1.sup_name 
, comparitive_statement1.tender_id
, comparitive_statement1.coc
, comparitive_statement1.shelf_life
, comparitive_statement1.make
, comparitive_statement1.datasheet
, quotation_items.supplier_name 
, quotation_items.tender_id 
FROM comparitive_statement1 
, quotation_items 
WHERE comparitive_statement1.tender_id = quotation_items.tender_id 
AND quotation_items.tender_id='$tender_id' 
and quotation_items.supplier_name = comparitive_statement1.sup_name 
group by quotation_items.supplier_name
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: i have added what i have tried.

Comment: using a inner join you can have the expected data visit [link] (http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: And what was the problem with the outcome? Show us sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: @PRANAV he is essentially doing an inner join with the join condition being in the where criteria.

Comment: Basically iam getting a 0 records... i dont know what iam doing wrong

Comment: basicaly i need to join two tables and print only records from comparitive where 

comparitive.sup_name is there in quotation.supplier_name

comparitive.tender_id = quotation.tender_id=$tender_id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cs.sup_name 
, cs.tender_id
, cs.coc
, cs.shelf_life
, cs.make
, cs.datasheet
, q.supplier_name 
FROM comparitive_statement1 cs
LEFT JOIN quatation_items q
ON cs.tender_id = q.tender_id
WHERE q.tender_id='$tender_id' 
AND q.supplier_name = cs.sup_name 
GROUP BY q.supplier_name
```

This query should work. Also, there is no point to have `comparitive_statement1.tender_id` and `quotation_items.tender_id` in the query as they will be identical.